# Mos amplifier numerical

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

[image]

Can anyone please explain how do I get this variation of Ix vs Vx curve?How do I determine whether the current will be in positive region or negetive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using KCL in the output node, you find that

$$I_X = i_{DS1} - i_{DS2}$$

(I'm using positive quantities for the PMOS here).

You can see that the current is *negative* if \$i_{DS1} < i_{DS2}\$. Otherwise, the current is positive. When is this the case?

For small \$V_X\$, M1 will not conduct a lot of current because of the small \$v_{DS}\$ applied. If \$V_X < v_{GS1} - V_{TH1}\$ then M1 is in the triode region.

For large \$V_X\$ we have the same situation for M2. It is in the triode region.

If \$V_{DD}\$ is large enough for one or both of the transistors to go into saturation, then the situation can change a little bit.

- M1 in *saturation*, M2 in *triode*

  M1 will behave like a current source, while M2 can be better approximated by a resistor. So the slope will be somewhat *linear*, but M1 will add a relatively constant current to \$I_X\$.
- M1 in *triode*, M1 in *saturation*

  The situation is identical, but the slope will be somewhat linear while M2 will *subtract* a constant current.
- M1 and M2 are *both in saturation*

  Both transistors act more or less like a current source, so the net current \$I_X\$ will be pretty much constant. However, because both transistor currents are slightly dependent on \$v_{DS}\$ (ie. *output impedance*), \$I_X\$ will not be perfectly constant.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed analysis.Another thing I would ask is what would happen if i replace the above pmos by a nmos?Will the graph be similar or somewhat change?

Comment: The graph will change. I suggest trying to predict what would happen, then take a simulator and see where you were correct and wrong. Make sure to connect the bulks of both NMOS to ground to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes I would have surely done that,but I am confused what values of Vb1 and Vb2  I should take.

Comment: Use a "standard" strong inversion biasing of \$v_{GS}-V_{TH} \approx 0.2V\$.